# Probability of a Minimum out of a Subset of a Set of Integers.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, order-statistics

Let us assume a set $\mathcal{A}$ of $K$ unique integers: $\mathcal{A} = (X_{1}, \ldots, X_{K})$ and randomly pick an integer $X_{j}$ from the set $\mathcal{A}$.

Now, let us draw a random subset $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{A} \setminus (X_{j})$ of $M < K-1$ integers (excluding the $X_{j}$ integer from the draw).

My problem is to find that the probability that the integer $X_{j}$ is less than the minimum integer in subset $\mathcal{B}$? That is, find/estimate the probability:

$\mathbb{P}(X_{j} < \min(X_{i}): X_{i} \in \mathcal{B})$.

Many thanks for your help!

Example: Let $\mathcal{A} = (2,3,4,5,6,7)$ and $X_{j} = 4$. Let also $\mathcal{B1} = (3,6,7)$ and $\mathcal{B2} = (6,7,5)$. In $\mathcal{B1}$, the integer $X_{j} = 4$ is not less that 3 = min(3,6,7), thus, does not satisfy the criterion, while in $\mathcal{B2}$, the integer $X_{j} = 4$ is less than 5 = min(5,6,7), which satisfies the criterion.

Comment: If you picked the $k$th ranked integer, how many of the $2^{K-1}$ subsets are there where the elements are each larger than $X_k$?

Comment: Note that you might as well set $\mathcal{A} = \{1,2,\cdots, K\},$ since all you care about is the uniqueness and the total ordering. It is good practice to clean up your question of spurious details such as all the $X_i$ notation, since it makes easier for people to parse your question.

Comment: Many thanks both!

Answer (score 2):

We order the element elements of $A$ from the min to max $x_{1},\dots,x_{k}$. Fix the chosen $x_{j}$ on the first step, then $\min{B} > x_{j}$ if and only if the set $B$ is a subset of $\{ x_{j+1}, \dots, x_{k}\}$, there are ${k-j}\choose{m}$ subsets of $m$ elements of this set, and of course, $j\leq k-m$ otherwise we can't pick $m$ elements greater than $x_{j}$; so
$$P(X_j\leq \min (B))=\sum\limits_{s=1}^{k-m}\frac{1}{k}\frac{{k-s}\choose{m}}{{k-1}\choose{m}}=\sum\limits_{i=m}^{k-1}\frac{1}{k}\frac{{i}\choose{m}}{{k-1}\choose{m}}$$

Now we use [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) identity to get
$$P(X_j\leq \min (B))=\frac{1}{k}\frac{{k}\choose{m+1}}{{k-1}\choose{m}}=\frac{1}{m+1}$$

Comment: Thank you!! Amazing abstraction of the problem.